# U.K. Youth mobility visa from Australian for 2 years expires

Tags: uk

Im an Australian living in the U.K. with my girlfriend (British). 
My visa started on August 2016 and it expires on August 2018.

My girlfriend is doing uni up until September 2018 and we would like to fly back to Australia together, however my visa will be expired by that time?

Is it possible that I can get an extension or work it some way that I can fly back to Australia with her?

Thanks

Comment: Is what you have a Tier 5 Youth Mobility visa?

Comment: Do you have to fly from the UK? Could you, for example, plan to fly from Paris after you spend a month in the Schengen zone?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot extend this visa: explicit among the conditions of the [Tier 5 Youth Mobility Scheme visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility) is that it cannot be extended.

However, as an Australian, you have the ability to enter many countries, either visa free or through visa waiver. As you're planning well in advance, you could explore those options, leaving the UK on schedule for nearby travels, before your partner joins you for the journey to Australia.

You could exit and re-enter the UK, although you might be challenged at the Border. Your landing interview:

- you're routinely stamped in for 6 months; after two years in the UK, girlfriend in the UK... not things in the plus column.
- you're given a temporary admission, days or several weeks; not a good thing on your record, should you ever wish to return.
- you're refused entry, removed; a really bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in [Dorothy's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/94480/19560), you could leave the UK for e.g. a Schengen zone vacation.

You can avoid the problem of returning to the UK by planning to travel to Australia from a Schengen zone city. Paris is an obvious choice because it has both direct train service from London and an international airport.